# Can we please ask information based questions?

Tags: discussion, homework

Sometimes there are questions that have answers in terms of information and dont need some explanation but often when i ask such questions i am told to first google it.(my questions have been put on hold as well) i wish to say that there are numerous sources that come on google and as a beginner in chemistry its really tough to gauge the authenticity or correctness of the information. **ChemSE is the most reliable source of any kind of information for me and hence i ask such questions here**. how could i improve this question asking trait to get beteer responses to my questions?

Comment: For starters, be more careful with punctuation and capitalisation. Another thing is that ChemSE *isn't* the most reliable source of info. Many answers are more or less incorrect, even highly upvoted ones. Generally I'd encourage to check Wikipedia first, at least for trivial stuff. It's still not 100 % reliable, but more accessible then sci. papers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally we do not want to give the impression that this site can give access to free personal researchers. We also want the quality of Q&A to: 1.) be of good quality 2.) show research effort and 3.) be useful to future visitors. I can't see any of your deleted without a tedious search but for example a question like "*why do acids neutralize bases*" might be useful but not quality and shows no research effort. If you ask about various databases or resources, these may be quality and researched but will change with time and not be useful to future visitors

If you have quick questions about source validity or recommendations feel free to ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table)

I want to clarify this is not to say you can't/shouldn't ask information questions sometimes they get popular enough to make the hot network questions list but do think about how it can be asked in light of the objectives of the site.